# How redirecting output from a function works in bash?

Tags: linux, bash

From what I've learned, also stated in the answer to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73150931/understanding-file-descriptor-duplication-in-bash), redirection of stdout works as follows:

When we do something like: `ls > dirlist`
bash does the followings:

1. forks a process, which still runs bash
2. in the subprocess, open the file `dirlist` for writing on file descriptor 1
3. calling `exec` passing to it the `ls` executable.

this way, when `ls` writes to FD 1, it actually writes to the file.

With this in mind, I wonder about the following:

```
$ foo() { echo "hello" ; }
$ foo > file
$ cat file
hello
```

as far as I know, functions run in the same shell process, so how does redirection works in that case?

Comment: same thing. bash fd 1 goes to file.

Comment: To really understand it, maybe start from http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/redir.c#n782 and go digging!

Answer (score 0):

Redirection itself is just a shell construct, so the shell can make it work however it wants. *Every* command, whether external processes or shell builtins, has its own idea of standard output, and standard output is inherited just as it is by child processes from parent processes. In this case, the command `foo` either inherits its standard output from the shell or takes whatever file a shell redirection specifies. Once inside the function, `echo` writes to whatever file *it* inherits from `foo`.

Put another way, for its own built-in commands (which includes functions, compound statements like `while`, `if`, etc) the shell effectively simulates `exec` without actually *calling* `exec`.

Comment: what do you mean that the "command foo inherits" etc.? the call foo doesn't start a new process, so there is no other process with its own copy of file descriptors. Likewise, what do you mean by "inside the file"? there is no file

Comment: "file" was a typo for "function". Processes are not the only thing that can inherit file descriptors. One can say that commands inherit file descriptors: new processes via `exec`, shell builtiins via the shell's implementation of built-ins.

Comment: The shell built-in `echo` writes to its standard output. The answer to "What is `echo`'s standard output?" is "Whatever the shell decides it is." The shell doesn't need to use `exec` to make that decision.